# NSURLConnection : JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsurlconnection

I get the following error from NSURLConnection connectionDidFinishLoading

> "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text
>   did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
>   set.) UserInfo=0x7b71dbb0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I used the following code :

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSError *error;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Loading Error = %@",error);
    }
}
```

The following is my json response :

```
{  
   "result":"success",
   "details":[  
      {  
         "id":"11531",
         "user_name":"",
         "fullname":"aa",
         "email_address":"aa",
         "user_type":"a",
         "server":"",
         "server_email":"",
         "server_password":"",
         "password":"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661",
         "clean_password":"a",
         "gender":"",
         "ceo_name":"",
         "ceo_picture":"",
         "ceo_contact":"",
         "ceo_contact_pic":"",
         "company_name":"a",
         "freight_company_name":"",
         "freight_company_email":"",
         "company_url":"11531",
         "company_keyword":"",
         "company_description":"",
         "address":"",
         "province":"",
         "postal_code":"",
         "phone_number":"",
         "fax_number":"",
         "website":"",
         "city":"",
         "b_category":"",
         "main_products":"",
         "cellphone":"a",
         "country":"0",
         "states":"",
         "company_status":"1",
         "joindate":"0",
         "varificationcode":"",
         "activation_status":"1",
         "new_email":"",
         "email_activation_status":"",
         "facebook_url":"",
         "twitter_url":"",
         "company_update_status":"0",
         "last_access_date":"0000-00-00",
         "ip_address":"",
         "ip_block":"0",
         "user_id":null,
         "company_id":null,
         "video_url":"",
         "oauth_uid":"",
         "oauth_provider":"",
         "get_color":"",
         "comp_name_size":"13",
         "member_type":"",
         "mark_status":"1",
         "ip_address_intension":"",
         "fbId":"",
         "twitterId":"",
         "profile_picture":"",
         "device_token":""
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried all the solutions in stackOverflow but in vein.

Comment: Did you try to set NSJSONReadingAllowFragments option?

Comment: By the way. Are you sure that your _urlData is completely contains your JSON in this place? I suppose you are appending it via NSURLConnections protocol methods. Just print [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] and you'll see.

Comment: @Krivoblotsky: That's a read herring. Clearly this is full JSON and not a fragment.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Answer (score 26):

Set option value to `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` instead of `kNilOptions`
I have tested your JSON taking it in a local file

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile
                                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                  error:&deserializingError];
```

Comment: Tried this, but it resulted in a more specific error: `(Cocoa error 3840.) (Invalid value around character 0.)`

Comment: It seems your json format is wrong. Check your json in online json parser

Comment: @MikeS, i think the response is in a string format, try this :
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]
I had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

NSLog the actual data that you are getting, not the string, and check the first bytes. JSONSerializer didn't find a { or a [ as the first character, so you probably have some zero bytes, or byte order marks, or some other invisible characters like that.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to Janmenjaya's answer i would like to add:-

I have faced this issue twice in different API's. The problem each time that i had was

1. First time the response that i was receiving was not in correct format. Remember the format must always start with a "[" or "{". So that was corrected from backend.
2. Secondly , i was trying to hit an URL which had a word "video" in it for ex http://www.xyz/video123.com and websites related to name video have been blocked in our office. Therefore ensure that the network that you are using has no such restrictions.
   Postman will show you correct response but in devices or simulators you will face issues.

Please ensure these cases also.