# Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 error in afnetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, afnetworking-2

i am unable to find solution of NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840  error in afnetworking 2.0

this is code i used

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:url parameters:inputs success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {

         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

this is the error getting

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521547/nsurlconnection-json-text-did-not-start-with-array-or-object-and-option-to-all

Comment: check your JSON is valid or not

Comment: where i can see my JSON is valid or not

Comment: JSON response which you are getting, may be invalid. To check whether it is valid or not, you should test it on www.hurl.com and check for valid json response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AFHTTPResponseSerializer instead

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Because you're using acceptableContentType of @"text/html", I assume you don't need a JSON serializer on response call. So this should be fine for your case.